# Symfony can't retrieve not mapped data from form to controller

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form, which is mapped to an object, and when I try to add not mapped field to this form, I can't retrieve the data.

This is my form :

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
            ->add('comment', TextareaType::class, [
                'label'=>'supidx.stateHistory.field.comment.short',
                    ]
            )
            ->add("file", FileType::class, [
                'label'=>false,
                'required'=>false,
                'mapped'=>false
            ])
    ;
}
```

Controller :

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
           $file = $form->get("file");
            dump($file);
```

Dump($file) returns null everytime.

I can't figure out why this doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you wish the field to be ignored when reading or writing to the object, you can set the mapped option to false.

Comment: did you `tried $file = $request->files->get('file');` ?

Comment: Yes, with $file = $request->files->get('file'); dump($file) is always null.

Comment: have you called `$form->handleRequest($request)`? before your if statement? (btw, you dont need 'isSubmitted', isValid checks automatically for that too.)

Answer (score 2):

If `file` is an object property, with an appropriate setter

```
$object->getFile();
```

Or if you want to retrieve any variable directly from your form

```
$form['file']->getData()
```